# Getting quote stream via fix-api 4.3

Tags: programming, market-data, fx, fix, quickfix

I'm new to FIX api,so far i did following (on QUICKFIX)

> 1. logged on to quote-session
> 2. subscribed to market data
> 3. sent "single-message" quote-request for an instrument (EUR/USD for example)
> 4. Finally i got response from fix-server (with current bid/ask/volume for symbol EUR/USD)

The problem is, it was a single response. I want to get nonstop ,real-time quote-feed on a blotter/panel(as can be seen in a trading-platform's 'quote-panel').

Comment: Did you set SubscriptionRequestType to Snapshot+Updates?

Comment: yes i sent 263=1 ,but still not sure if I got mulitple levels/tiers of open book

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure IT question (hence off topic)

Comment: No It's not. This question is also associated  with FIX-API workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASSUMING your counterparty does stream data (this is not a given), what you got was a Snapshot, requesting the top of the book and the volume. I am assuming you sent a MarketDataRequest message, which is 35=V. The tag 35 in FIX protocol is the Message Type. For help with the protocol, [FIXIMATE](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) is your friend.

Most counterparties should have documentation which tells you how they implement FIX. Look for information on how they handle MarketDataRequest messages. Just as amsh has said in a comment,  in your 35=V message you need to request Snapshot+Updates. This means you need to set the SubscriptionRequestType (tag 263) to the value 1. You probably did not set it at all, and it likely defaulted to 0.

Comment: I checked thoroughly & found i did send 263=1, but still, i got a single response containing one BID,one ASK & their Volumes( not price-tiers/bids/asks). How can i get all price-tiers of the whole book?(market depth)

Comment: At least two things can be happening -- 1) your counterparty does not provide this information. Have you checked with them? Perhaps you have a demo account, etc. 2) you could be sending another message 35=V with tag 263=2 (Unsubscribe) immediately after you subscribe. Look at your FIX logs to try to troubleshoot.

Comment: solved this by sending 265=0(Full Refresh) & 264=N>1

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, but I'll take your word for it...